# Differential Equations Constants

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Help! I'm going nuts with all the constants! consider this equation: $y'+5y=0$. When you getting to the integral part: $\int y^{-1}\,dy=\int-5\,dx$. After the integration $\ln(y)+c_1=-5x+c_2$. Now we have 2 $c$'s. When I use a calculator I don't know where the $c_2$ disappears:

---

[image]$%[1]https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/4b88830c-771e-4b55-9c27-4a111c13b941.png.$

---

They write combine the constants. This is not changing the result? And how do I know it's $y=-5x+c$ and not $y=-5x-c$? Thanks.

Comment: Well constants are arbitrary. $c \in \Bbb R$ so you can replace all with just one constant...

Comment: Rightly said...

Comment: A constant added to another constant is just another constant, So it doesn't matter when you combine them, what they're doing is $\ln(y)=-5x+(C_1-C_2)$, and then $(C_1-C_2)=C$, you can put a '$-C$ there but it still doesn't matter, as you'll find the same result when using the initial conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's something weird with the provided solution. Simply :

$$y'+5y = 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{y'}{y}=-5 \Rightarrow \int \frac{y'}{y}dx = \int -5dx \Leftrightarrow \ln |y(x)| = -5x+c $$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$|y(x)| = e^{-5x+c} =e^{-5x}e^c$$

Now if you simply let $c := e^c$, you yield the expression  :

$$|y(x)| = ce^{-5x}$$

due to the fact that the constant $c \in \mathbb R$ is arbitrary so you can "replace" it to whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem lies in this line
$$-\frac{1}{5}\ln(y)c_2=t+c_1$$ and then we have
$$-\frac{1}{5}\ln(y)=t+c_1-c_2$$ then you can define $$C=c_1-c_2$$